# How can I install and run MDbg on macOS from the dotnet command line?

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-core

I'm trying to install and run the Managed debugger (MDbg) from dotnet core.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MDbg/0.1.0

says I can run `dotnet add package MDbg --version 0.1.0`.

This adds a dependency to a CS project but does not give me access to an MDbg executable.

What do I need to do to access a command line debugger for C#?

I don't want to use VSCode or Visual Studio to access a debugger, I want to debug from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MDbg` can only be used to debug full .NET Framework applications (and only on windows). There is an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1145) to port it to .NET Core, but as of now it's not done yet. Here is [documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/debugging-instructions.md) link describing different available options to debug .NET Core applications (including on OSX).